# Referencing variables in an img src to make a link?

Tags: javascript, image, variables, src

I'm trying to put a string and a number together so a variable is in an image link, and so the variable formed by the string and number's value would display in the link, but instead the raw name just displays, not the variable's value.

```
      var link1 = 'restOfLink.gif';

      var myFunction = function(number){

      var imgLink = 'http://i60.tinypic.com/';

      var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1);

          $("div").append("<img src = '"+imgLink+'link'+randomNumber+"'/>");
       }
```

randomNumber won't always be 1 but let's just assume it is.
The link shows up as http://i60.tinypic.com/link1.gif
Any help on that? I'm trying to make an app that displays a new random image when a div is clicked. (the code above isn't all of the code, but it's enough to cover my problem)

Comment: sorry I accidentally pressed enter, give me a second to edit :)

Comment: I suggest you also make a jsfiddle

Comment: some examples that illustrate the problem/context would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to create a dynamic `img` element with a variable as the link or part of it you could do:

```
//These are just example variables, you can use your own the same way.
var imgPath = '/images/blog/';
var size = '200x450';

document.createElement('img').src =  imgPath + 'yourImage' + size + '.png';
```

[**JsFiddle Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/wQJ53/)

---

For your example i would suggest creating an array of links that you can access using a random number, for example:

```
var links = ['restOfLink.gif', 'anotherexample.png', 'yetanother.jpg'];
```

To select a particular image from inside the `links array` you need to pass it the index it occurs at, with `0` being the first.

So for example:

```
links[0] --> "restOfLink.gif"
links[1] --> "anotherexample.png"
links[2] --> "yetanother.jpg"
```

See this [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kyleNeedham/8UWy5/3/) demo using this method.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still not able to produce the result I wanted, though.
I have the variables: var link1 = '2c0yyr.gif'; and var imgPath = 'http://i60.tinypic.com/'; and var randomNumber = 1;
Now in the image.src, I want to be able to change link it to a certain variable, and I want it to be changeable what variable it links to, like: image.src =  imgPath + 'link'+1; would link to the variable link1. Is this possible?

Comment: @Hexman I think i understand what your trying to do now, I have updated my answer and included a new **Jsfiddle**.

Comment: That answers my question perfectly! Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

You should create the link string by concatenating the different parts in Javascript, and update the img src attribute afterwards. Something like:

```
var bar = 3;
var linkString = "http://www.foo.com/image_number_" + bar + ".jpg";

document.getElementById("yourImgId").src = linkString;
```

Best.

Answer (score -2):

Dont know what you want. A JSFiddle would help as suggested but here is my try at a answer:

```
string = "lol";
number = 1;
source = string+number;

$(".element").attr('src', source+".jpg");
```

You need JQuery for this though.